# Not Able to start Deployer Service and Discovery Service after Sdl Web 8.5 Install

Tags: deployer, discovery

I'm try configuring discovery service and deployer service execute scripts include in this web and execute JAR File discovery-registration.jar but always show me issue and don't let start services SDL Web Discovery Service and SDL Web Deployer Service, where always restart server for modify changes, but continue with service down.

Best Regards

Comment: hi, can you please provide exceptions, some stack traces and details so that we can help you with the issue. it can be caused by numerous reasons, so having stack trace can help pinpoint issue

Comment: Welcome to Tridion StackExchange, Please share any logs error messages in discovery and deployer?

Comment: 2019-10-09 23:59:52,135 DEBUG EventDispatcher - TMA-AG-00000 No event to process
2019-10-09 23:59:54,150 DEBUG EventDispatcher - TMA-AG-00000 No event to process
2019-10-09 23:59:56,166 DEBUG EventDispatcher - TMA-AG-00000 No event to process
2019-10-09 23:59:58,167 DEBUG EventDispatcher - TMA-AG-00000 No event to process

Comment: This message in file cd_monitor.xml

Comment: Not indicate message in log specifical

Comment: Rather than having a conversation about logging output here in the comments, please edit the question to include the logging output. In this way, the question itself is a complete report of the problem which we can all use for future reference. That said, I doubt logging from cd_monitor.xml is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Usually when one of the services doesn't start, what actually happens is that it runs for a short amount of time, and during its startup phase discovers that there's some reason it can't run normally. In this case, it will stop, but not before writing lots of interesting things in the logs. In most cases, there'll be enough there to help you solve the problem.

So, in the config folder of your service, look in the logback.xml and check the log.folder property. The first thing to check is whether you can find logging output in this location. If not, check that the account running your service has permission to write there.

Assuming there's logging to see, check what it says. Sometimes the relevant information is in the file matching the service itself (cd_deployer..log) but often you'll also have to look in cd_core..log.

If this doesn't solve your problem, set the log.level property in logback.xml to DEBUG. At the bottom of the file, set the level property of the root element to DEBUG. Restart your services and check the logging again.

Reading carefully through the logs will usually get you there. If you don't understand what you see there, you can ask here. If you still can't find the answer, and you end up raising a support ticket, you can guarantee that the first thing they'll ask for is debug logging, so it's always well-spent effort. Good luck.

Comment: When activa mode DEBUG in log cd_core indicate this message ERROR ServiceContainer - Could not load ServiceContainer